# CSS3 multiple animation: not clear at all

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a simple animation that consists of multiple images coming from diferent directions and finally aligning each one next to the other. This is by only using CSS3, without using javascript. However, since I haven't done any animation with it, I'm pretty confused and I'm pretty sure I'm not doing it properly. This is the jsfiddle with code of what I've done right now, and *it's working as intended*:

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qu88xkee/6/)

Nevertheless I'm confused because I don't understand the `@-webkit-keyframes` / `@keyframes` rule.

On the first img (red one) it moves exactly from left `0px` to `300px`, while the second img (blue) should move from left `400px` to `-100px`, so technically it would go outside and disappear, yet it moves behind next to the img1.

Last but not least, the third img (green) should be next to the blue one and would outside together, but it moves right behind it.

Why is it? Could someone explain me easily how does animation work please? Is there a better way to do it?

In case the link doesn't work, this is the code:

**HTML**

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/css.css" />
</head>
<body>
        <div id="img1"/>
        <div id="img2"/>
        <div id="img3"/>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
#img1, #img2, #img3 {
    width: 100px;
    height: 30px;
    position: relative;
}

#img1 {
    background: red;
    -webkit-animation: first 5s infinite; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    animation: first 5s infinite;
}

#img2 {
    background: blue;
    -webkit-animation: second 5s infinite; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    animation: second 5s infinite;
}

#img3 {
    background: green;
    -webkit-animation: third 5s infinite; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    animation: third 5s infinite;
}

/* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
@-webkit-keyframes first {
    from {left: 0px;}
    to {left: 300px;}
}

@keyframes first {
    from {left: 0px;}
    to {left: 300px;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes second {
    from {left: 400px;}
    to {left: -100px;}
}

@keyframes second {
    from {left: 400px;}
    to {left: -100px;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes third {
    from {left: 300px;}
    to {left: -100px;}
}

@keyframes third {
    from {left: 300px;}
    to {left: -100px;}
}
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Animating `translateX()` (more about [transform on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/transform)) instead of `left` property *could* be GPU accelerated on some/many browsers. Drawback: it isn't compatible with IE8 (and you're never certain that it'll be GPU accelerated) but CSS3 Animation isn't compatible with IE8 or IE9 so it isn't a problem here! (sources: caniuse.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because `#img1`, `#img2`, `#img3` are in relative position... You want an animation relative to the browser window so you have to use fixed positioning.

```
#img1, #img2, #img3 {
    width: 100px;
    height: 30px;
    position: fixed;
}
```

Working demo : [Fiddler](https://jsfiddle.net/qu88xkee/7/)

(More information about [CSS Positioning](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position))

Comment: Oh, I just didn't notice the position was on relative... Geez.. Thanks a lot, but is it the best way to do it (I'm talking about CSS and keyframes rules)? Or is there an optimal way?

Answer (score 1):

I hope I understood your problem correctly. You're using the shorthand-close syntax on your `div` tags which should only be used on certain tags (e.g. `img`).
Your HTML code results in this structure:

```
    <div id="img1">
      <div id="img2">
        <div id="img3"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Change it to:

```
<div id="img1"></div>
<div id="img2"></div>
<div id="img3"></div>
```

If you want to align all divs in one line either set their `position` to `absolute` or move `#img2` and `#img3` up:

```
#img1, #img2, #img3 {
    width: 100px;
    height: 30px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

or

```
#img1, #img2, #img3 {
    width: 100px;
    height: 30px;
    position: relative;
}

#img2 {
    ...
    top: -30px;
}

#img3 {
    ...
    top: -60px;
}
```